# How to show that something does not belong to PROP

Tags: logic, self-learning

I am trying wrap my mind around how to show that something does not belong to PROP. Just for clarification:

The set PROP of propositions is the smallest set $X$ with the properties

(i) $p_{i} \in X \quad (i \in \mathbb{N}), \bot \in X$

(ii) $\phi, \psi \in X \implies (\phi \square \psi) \in X$

(iii) $\phi \in X \implies \neg \phi \in X$

As an example, how would I go about proving $(( \to \not \in \text{PROP}$? My problem is that I do not know how to interpret the information, i.e. $(( \to \not \in \text{PROP}$, in the context of the definition. What I would want to do is to suppose that $(( \to$ satisfy all the three criteria and then show that it is $\textbf{not}$ the smallest set.

Comment: To help clarify your question: is "$(( \to$" an operator, i.e., does it have signature $(( \to : X \times X \rightarrow X$ (akin to $\Box$ in condition (ii))?

Comment: Since none of your formation rules involve the character $\to$, no proposition contains that character.

Answer (score 1):

First look at $((\to$ and see it does not fit (i) as it is not of the form $p_i$. Nor does it fit (iii) since it does not begin with $\lnot$. So the only possibility is that it fits (ii) which is of the form $(\phi,\psi)$ where then $\phi$ must start with $(\to$, because the first left parenthesis of $((\to$ has been "peeled off" in making it match (ii).

Now apply the same idea with $(\to$ and see as before it can only match (ii) and another parenthesis gets peeled off and you're left with just $\to$, whose first (and only) symbol cannot match the beginning of any of (i),(ii),(iii), so the whole thing is not in PROP.